# Slow storage writes: how many milliseconds exactly? SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, storage

We're running SQL Server 2008 R2.

I'm using SPBlitz and it's saying that I have slow storage writes on Drive H. Blitz defines these as "averaging over 20ms."

But of course, someone asked "How much over?"

Is there a query I can use to determine what the average storage writes is in milliseconds?

Thanks,
mh

Answer (score 6):

You can query `sys.dm_io_virtual_file_stats` to find out the read and write latency.

You can use the script from [here](https://gist.github.com/TheRockStarDBA/a40aac45a76bc5ed3c26) or [here - this is snip from my project of designing a comprehensive SQL Server health checker](https://gist.github.com/TheRockStarDBA/fdfad12a3961c9f3e507) *(this is something internal for now, but planning to opensource the code soon - as a thank you to sql server community !)*.

Also, read this blog post by  Erin Stellato - [What Virtual Filestats Do, and Do Not, Tell You About I/O Latency](http://sqlperformance.com/2013/10/t-sql-queries/io-latency). This blog post has a script that you can use as well.